# code optimization for grepl function on large dataframe (dplyr)

Tags: r, debugging, optimization, dplyr

I'm trying to create code that essentially looks for certain key words within a string and tick off an indicator if that key word was found. I've done this in the past using an ifelse-grepl but for some reason in this context I get a whole bunch of errors if I don't collect the table before applying the iflese-grepl mutates. This is leading to like 10-20min queries since the data I am working with is quite large. Code is included below, any suggestions?

```html
currentdate <- Sys.Date()

df <- sc %>% tbl(tblsan(rawdata)) %>%
  filter(between (as.Date(createtime), as.Date("2022-11-01"), as.Date(currentdate))) %>%
  select(id,text) %>% collect() %>%
  mutate(text = tolower(text),
         ind1 = ifelse(grepl("keyword1", text,fixed = TRUE),1,0),
         ind2 = ifelse(grepl("keyword2", text, fixed = TRUE),1,0)) %>%
  select(id,ind1,ind2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(ind1 = sum(ind1),ind2 = sum(ind2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ind1 = if_else(ind1>=1,1,0),
         ind1 = if_else(ind1>=1,1,0)) %>%
  select(id,ind1,ind2)
```

Just for some context im working with a table which has (for the purpose of this post) an ID, text and date column. There are many rows with the same ID's in this data (with different text) but the desired output would simply have one indicator per ID if the keywords occur in any of the corresponding text columns (hence the summarise function).

---

Also, here is the error I get if I leave the collect function until the end: (I use IMPALA to query)

> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) :
> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1412: 00000: [RStudio][ImpalaODBC] (360) Syntax error occurred during query execution: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 13:
> ... confirmed', `text`, TRUE AS `fixed`)) THEN 1.0 WHEN N...
> ^
> Encountered: AS
> Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, IGNORE, HAVING, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, OFFSET, OR, ORDER, RANGE, REGEXP, RLIKE, ROWS, UNION, COMMA

```
CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
 
In addition: Warning messages:
1. Named arguments ignored for SQL grepl (repeats 4 times)
```

---

Sample rawdata table:

| ID | TEXT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 1-1-1 |
| 1 | dft | 1-1-1 |
| 1 | thj | 1-1-2 |
| 2 | ddd | 1-2-2 |
| 3 | ttt | 1-1-2 |

for the purpose of this code, date can be ignored. The first example indicator will be the presence of the **letter d**, the second will be the presence of the **letter t**.

The first manipulation will do:

| ID | IND1 | IND2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

and finally, after the summarise : (only a single occurrence is needed to spit out 1 in the indicator)

| ID | IND1 | IND2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide code sufficient for us to recreate `rawdata`?

Comment: @jpsmith I will add a sample table and output!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `summarize` here in the following way. `any` looks for, well, "any" `TRUE` from `grepl` and returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The `+` converts the boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 1/0, respectively, eliminating the need for several lines in your original code (`mutate(...) %>% ...`), etc):

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID TEXT    DATE
1   abcd    1-1-1
1   dft 1-1-1
1   thj 1-1-2
2   ddd 1-2-2
3   ttt 1-1-2", h = TRUE)

df %>% 
  summarize(IND1 = +any(grepl("D", TEXT, ignore.case = TRUE)),
            IND2 = +any(grepl("T", TEXT, ignore.case = TRUE)),
            .by = ID)

## Or for older versions of dplyr

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(IND1 = +any(grepl("D", TEXT, ignore.case = TRUE)),
            IND2 = +any(grepl("T", TEXT, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
  ID IND1 IND2
1  1    1    1
2  2    1    0
3  3    0    1
```

Comment: your simplification would've been perfect but it seems as though the same error pops up

Comment: @A03 hmm it seems like it might not be an issue with the code, but something with your database/data - though unfortunately we cant see what's in the `sc %>% tbl(tblsan(rawdata)) %>% ...` part of your script. What packages is `tblsan` from?

Answer (score 0):

For this sample of 1M rows of strings, your code takes a couple seconds on my machine. How large is your data?

```
library(dplyr)
my_strings <- data.frame(id = sample(1:1e5, 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                         text = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1E6, 5, '[A-Z]'))

my_strings %>%
  mutate(text = tolower(text),
         ind1 = ifelse(grepl("d", text,fixed = TRUE),1,0),
         ind2 = ifelse(grepl("t", text, fixed = TRUE),1,0)) %>%
  summarise(ind1 = max(ind1),ind2 = max(ind2), .by = id)
```

It goes about twice as fast with:

```
my_strings %>%
  mutate(text = tolower(text),
         ind1 = stringr::str_detect(text, "d") * 1,
         ind2 = stringr::str_detect(text, "t") * 1) %>%
  summarise(ind1 = max(ind1),ind2 = max(ind2), .by = id)
```

For 10M rows and 1M id's, both methods take about 20 seconds on my machine. About half the time is the final summing per group, and that can be made about 2x as fast by using `dtplyr` to use `data.table`. How big is the data and how fast is good enough for your use case?